# Convert all children of a div to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a div and I want to convert all of its children to an array.
So the expected output from this should be:

```
numbers = ['<div>Lorem ipsum<h1>Dolores</h1><h2>Test</h2>Lorem final<div>']
```

HTML

```
<div>
 Lorem ipsum
 <h1>Dolores</h1> 
 <h2>Test</h2>
 Lorem final
<div>
```

JS

```
convertToArray() {
    let numbers = Document.querySelector(':scope > div');
    // let numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
    // let numbers = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);  
    // console.log(Array.from(numbers));
    console.log(numbers);
}
```

The logged result is always empty.

I tried using a couple of ES5 & ES6 answers found on stackoverflow, but none of them work when applied to all the children of an element.

Comment: Your expected output just seems to be one item which is all of the html

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything related to an 'array' about this - it's just the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) string of the `div`...? Am I missing something.

Comment: also `document` should have a small d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is as follows, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// declaring the function as an Arrow function, passing in
// a CSS selector:
const convertToArray = (selector) => {
  // using document.querySelectorAll() to find all instances of
  // the elements matching the selector, with an Array literal
  // and spread syntax to convert the NodeList into an Array
  // of nodes:
  let sources = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
  // iterating over the Array of nodes, with Array.prototype.map()
  // to return a new Array based on the first:
  return sources.map(
    // an Arrow function passing the current node ('el') into
    // the function, retrieving its Element.outerHTML property
    // and returning that as the new Array-element:
    (el) => el.outerHTML
  );
}

console.log(convertToArray('div'));
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum
  <h1>Dolores</h1>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  Lorem final
</div>
```

References:

- [Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).